# how to run process in background using gcloud ssh

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have to gcp linux VMs, with that I am doing ssh from one instance to another and running process using below command, that works fine but when I use option to run process in background, the command shows no results.

1. gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {instance-name} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log' ==== This works fine
2. gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {instance-name} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log &' === This does not gets executed.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue using the instruction provided in this [google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/VQ3UqgkxaE8/SHNRoUfOCgAJ)?

Comment: cross-posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/461210/72456

Answer (score 0):

The second command has a problem.

```
gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {instance-name} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log &'
```

Notice the `&` at the end of the command. The commands between the quotes starting with `cd` are executed from left to right. The last command `nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log &` is where the `&` was placed which means to run that command in the background. This will not have the intended affect.

Also, nohup needs to run in the foreground in order to setup the process in the background without a terminal. Adding the `&` breaks this program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want this process to run in background that is why added &, if this is not correct then how I can make the startWeblogic process run in background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the ampersand `&` at the end of the command so the whole SSH will run in the background without affecting the command sent. Also the SSH command will exit, so if you want to keep the command running you should use `nohup` for it:

```
nohup gcloud compute ssh --zone=ZONE INSTANCE_NAME -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log' &
```